# cant acces jupyter notebook variable from previous session

Tags: jupyter-notebook

So, im playing around with jupyter notebook, and I have this code, that i wrote yesterday:

[image]

BUt the problem is, that when i try to acces my model object the next day. Jupyter does not allow me to do that
[image]

For some reason i am not able to acces the variables in cells that i wrote i a previous session. Why is this? and how do I circumvent?

Answer (score 0):

If you shut down the Jupyter Notebook service this is to be expected. Your output and cell numbers are saved in the notebook, but objects actually do not stay in memory. Notice how you have `In [4]:` in both screenshots. This is because you restarted the service and the second screenshot shows your 4th run of that cell since the restart.

You need to rerun the entire notebook to load everything into memory. You can use Kernel> Restart & Run All from the top menu to do this automatically.

Comment: okay, do i need to run each cell, or is there a button for running everything?

Comment: In the top menu, select Kernel>Restart & Run All. If my answer helped you, please consider marking it "accepted" and give it an up.